# Filtering a collection with LINQ to SQL, based on condition that involves other rows

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I am getting a dataset using LINQ to SQL. I need to filter this dataset such that:

If a field with a null SourceName exists and there's at least one other record for this field with a non-null SourceName, then it should be removed.

If it is the only row for that 'Field', then it should remain in the list.

Here's an example data: Data consists of 3 columns: 'Field', 'SourceName' and 'Rate'

```
Field | SourceName |  Rate 
 10   |    s1      |   9   
 10   |    null    |   null
 11   |    null    |   null
 11   |    s2      |   5
 11   |    s3      |   4
 12   |    null    |   null
 13   |    null    |   null
 13   |    s4      |   7
 13   |    s5      |   8
  8   |    s6      |   2
  9   |    s7      |   23
  9   |    s8      |   9
  9   |    s9      |   3
```

Output should look like:

```
Field | SourceName | Rate 
 10   |  s1        |  9   
 11   |  s2        |  5
 11   |  s3        |  4
 12   |  null      |  null    //  <- (remains since there's only 
 13   |  s4        |  7       //      1 record for this 'Field')
 13   |  s5        |  8
  8   |  null      |  null
  9   |  s8        |  9
  9   |  s9        |  3
```

How do I filter it?

Comment: What's the object type?  Normally you can filter a collection with something like: `filteredList = unfilteredList.Where(i => i.SourceName != null);`

Comment: @David - I guess that can't be done. That would remove any row with a null sourcename. I want the row to remain if it is the only row in the dataset. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Veena: Then a more complex `Where` clause, but the process is still the same.  Maybe something like: `.Where(i => (i.SourceName != null) || ((i.SourceName == null) && (unfilteredList.Where(j => j.Field == i.Field).Count() == 1)))`  This is all freehand so it may not be perfect, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: @blachshma - I created another list, copied all rows with a not null sourcename. Then run a foreach loop in the original dataset and checking for records with null sourcename if they exist in the new list. If not trying to add it. I was wondering if there's a better way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: @David - This portion of the expression isn't returning any records (((i.SourceName == null) && (unfilteredList.Where(j => j.Field == i.Field).Count() == 1))). Do you have any links where I can read a bit abt this topic? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can read up on LINQ in a _lot_ of places.  Google can get you started.  You'll need to tinker with your code and meaningfully debug things, I'm afraid Stack Overflow isn't here to deliver production-ready code for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not trivial and can't be solved with just a `.Where()` clause. Your filter criteria depends on a condition that requires grouping, so you will have to `.GroupBy()` and then flatten that collection of collections using `.SelectMany()`.

The following code satisfies your expected output using LINQ to Objects, and I don't see any reason for LINQ to SQL not to be able to translate it to SQL, haven't tried that tough.

```
        //Group by the 'Field' field.
yourData.GroupBy(x => x.Field)

        //Project the grouping to add a new 'IsUnique' field
        .Select(g => new { 
                        SourceAndRate = g,
                        IsUnique = g.Count() == 1,
        })

        //Flatten the collection using original items, plus IsUnique
        .SelectMany(t => t.SourceAndRate, (t, i) => new {
                        Field = t.SourceAndRate.Key,
                        SourceName = i.SourceName, 
                        Rate = i.Rate,
                        IsUnique = t.IsUnique
        })

        //Now we can do the business here; filter nulls except unique
        .Where(x => x.SourceName != null || x.IsUnique);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq's built in 'Where' clause with a lambda continuation:

Simple static example of using lambda's and a simple POCO class to store the data in a list like yours:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Simple
{
    class Program
    {
        class Data
        {
            public string Field { get; set; }
            public string SourceName { get; set; }
            public string Rate { get; set; }
        }

        static List<Data> Create()
        {
            return new List<Data>
                {
                    new Data {Field = "10", SourceName = null, Rate = null},
                    new Data {Field = "11", SourceName = null, Rate = null},
                    new Data {Field = "11", SourceName = "s2", Rate = "5"}
                };
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ls = Create();

            Console.WriteLine("Show me my whole list: \n\n");

            // write out everything
            ls.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Field + "\t" + x.SourceName + "\t" + x.Rate + "\n"));


            Console.WriteLine("Show me only non nulls: \n\n");

            // exclude some things
            ls.Where(l => l.SourceName != null)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Field + "\t" + x.SourceName + "\t" + x.Rate + "\n"));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```